# Some Blank lines coming up while generating csv format

Tags: java, jsp, csv

when generating csv format , i am getting some first twelve blank lines coming up and datas are appending from 13th line onwards.  Kindly help how to ignore first twelve empty lines on csv report and datas should start from first line itself. Below is my sample code.

```
if(excelParam.equals("csv")){
        ServletOutputStream stream = response.getOutputStream();
        StringBuffer stoppedTxnRowSB = new StringBuffer();
        response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=UTF-8");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=\"sample.csv\"");
        response.addHeader("Content-description", reportTitle);
for(int i=0; i < reportHeader.length; i++){
            if(i ==  (samHead.length -1)){
                row.append(samHead[i] + "\n");
            }
             else{
                row.append(samHead[i]+", ");
            } 
        }
stream.print(stoppedTxnRowSB.toString());
        stream.flush();
        return;
```

Comment: You fill the outputStream with `stoppedTxnRowSB`. You should check it. Your code is incomplete. What is the for-loop for?